# python multiprocessing shared memory array doesn't allow 2-d array

Tags: python, memory-management, process, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I would like to store a 2-d array as shared memory array, so each process created by multiprocessing module can access the 2-d array. But it seems only vector is allowed. If I change the shape in the following example from (6,1) to (2,3), the example won't work and it says "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array
import numpy as np

def f(n,a):
    a[:] = np.ones(shape=(6,1), dtype=float)[:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tmp =  np.zeros(shape=(6,1), dtype=float)
    print tmp

    arr = Array('f', tmp)

    p1 = Process(target=f, args=(1,arr))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()

    print 'done'
    print arr[:]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [`mutiprocessing.Array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) is a wrapper around python's [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#array.array) type, not `numpy.ndarray` and python's `array` type doesn't support multiple dimensionality.  Specifically, look at the documentation for the `initializer`:

> A new array whose items are restricted by typecode, and initialized from the optional initializer value, which must be a list, string, or *iterable over elements of the appropriate type*.

You've got an iterable (a multi-dimensional array), but it yields views/arrays, not elements of the appropriate type.

Comment: Is there a quick way to convert numpy.ndarray to array?

Comment: @readRead -- Only 1D numpy arrays can be converted to `array` -- and it makes a copy (not a view)

Comment: Thanks. I plan to do some matrix manipulation on the shared array in each process. If I just store 1-d array, it's not very convenient. How can I shared a 2-d numpy array across processes and avoid copy? maybe use something other than multiprocessing.Array?

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced it's possible.  As far as I see it, the best you can do is create a wrapper around the `Array`/`array` which provides a nicer interface.

Comment: If I create a wrapper around Array/array, which converts 1-d array to 2-d numpy.ndarray, does this involves extra copy?

Comment: @readRead -- Yep.  That would involve a copy.  As far as I know, there's no way for a numpy.ndarray and an array.array to share data.